# function returns strings - how to add them to a list as separate items?

Tags: python-3.x, list, function

I'm struggling with getting the output from a function to the format I'd like (list would be easiest (I think) for working with). Any help would be appreciated.

What I have

```
def adf_filter():
    for row in adfstats.itertuples():
        if float(row.adf) <= float(row.critvalues['10%']):
            print(str(row.Index))

adf_filter()
```

returns something like:

ETH_LTC
DASH_XMR
ETC_NXT
XMR_BTC
ETC_XRP
DASH_LSK
DASH_BTC
DASH_LTC
DOGE_NXT

What I've tried:

```
adfpass = []

def adf_filter():
    for row in adfstats.itertuples():
        if float(row.adf) <= float(row.critvalues['10%']):
            adfpass.append(str(row.Index))
            return adfpass

adf_filter()
```

which returns ['ETH_LTC'] i.e., only the first item.

Is there a way to make it return all the items as a list? i.e., ['ETC_LTC','DASH_XMR',etc]

I've found some answers for java and similar but not quite the same for python that I haven't been able to figure out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use list comprehension:

```
def adf_filter():
    return [str(row.Index) for row in adfstats.itertuples() if float(row.adf) <= float(row.critvalues['10%'])]
```

PD: I havent tested it yet, but it should work

Now, going to your specific problem, you have the return statement inside the for when it should go outside:

```
def adf_filter():
    for row in adfstats.itertuples():
        if float(row.adf) <= float(row.critvalues['10%']):
            adfpass.append(str(row.Index))

    return adfpass
```

Comment: Thanks Abend, that was a huge help. Works a treat and has saved me so much time further on with similar problems too.

Answer (score 0):

You've got all the right pieces, just not in the right order:

```
def adf_filter():
    adfpass = []

    for row in adfstats.itertuples():
        if float(row.adf) <= float(row.critvalues['10%']):
            adfpass.append(str(row.Index))

    return adfpass
```

Nothing about this arrangement is Python specific, it's just general programming.